# Modifying data in one component based on a state of parallel component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components rendered parallelly in the main component:

```
<div id="main">
  <data-component/>
  <filters-component/>
</div>
```

The data component handles the data:

```
export default {
    name: 'data',
    data: {
        someData: {},
    },
    template: "<p v-for="entry in someData">{{ entry }}</p>",
}
```

And the filters component renders some form selects which should filter the data from above:

```
export default {
    name: 'filters',
    methods: {
        filterChanged: event => { this.$data.someData = event.target.name }
    },
    template: "<select v-on:click="filterChanged"><option value="foo">bar</option></select>",
}
```

In the filters component I have an event handler - I want to change the data of the `data component` in there and make it re-render. I cannot do this as the `data-component` is not the parent of the `filters-component`, so I can't use the props to pass down variables.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: wrap them in a parent component and handle the data in that parent, pass it down as props to each component

Comment: Or use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

Comment: Ah, vuex, never heard of it but seems like a perfect solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're still not familiar with vuex and only building a small app, you can try this https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/ . But if you're building a large app, just use vuex.

Answer (score 0):

Vuex and global event bus are for situations you want to share data between really distant components, here it's just one parent, two children, so you can [pass props down, and propagate child changed data with events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events), the template should look like something like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <data-component v-bind:array="filteredArr"/>
  <filters-component v-on:change="filterChanged"/>
</div>
```

For the `script` part, in `filters-component`, you propagate the `change` event with the new filter condition, like [`this.$emit('change', 'new condition');`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit). And in the parent you have `filterChanged` in your `methods` to handle the new condition and change the array for `data-component`.